# How do I turn a textbox into a date or currency textbox using only JavaScript (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, currency

I am trying to build a form using only JavaScript and jQuery.  For one of the textboxes, I need to make it display as a date.  And another as American Currency.

I have seen a few really cool forms before where it already has the " / /" symbols in there, and as you type the date, it falls perfectly into the symbols so you don't have to type them.  Also, I need it to display as a date in the same format (mm/dd/yyyy) when a button is clicked.  In addition, somehow, I need it where if no dates were entered, it displays nothing when the button is pushed.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so, after looking around online, I found a better way to describe what I am looking for for the date.  It is exactly the same as the HTML5

```
<input type="date">
```

However, after clicking the button, I need it to display as MM/DD/YYYY and the HTML5 only allows YYYY-MM-DD which is NOT what I want.

So, how do I build a single textbox that has the same functions (I don't need the date picker) as the HTML5 "date", but with the display formate as MM/DD/YYYY after a button is clicked?

Comment: FYI `type="date"` is supported differently depending on the browser. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/form-inputs-browser-support-issue/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was browsing online and in other forums, and found this answer:

```
 $('#date').keyup(function(){
      if ($(this).val().length == 2){
           $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
      }
      else if ($(this).val().length == 5){
           $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of input is not trivial.  There's some finesse that you'll need to do.  First the HTML:

```
<div id="dateInput">
    <input type="number" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2"/>/<input type="number" placeholder="DD" maxlength="2"/>/<input type="number" placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="4"/>
</div>

<div id="moneyInput">
    $<input type="number"/>
</div>
```

Now basic CSS, we'll remove the borders from the inputs and instead add them to the containers:

```
input{
   border:none;
   background:transparent;
}

div{
   border:1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

Here's the hardest part, the Javascript/jQuery.  The money one should work natively but the date one will take some work.

```
$('#dateInput').on('input', function(){
   //get max length of the input
   var maxLength = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));
   //get the current value of the input
   var currentValue = $(this).val();
   //if the current value is equal to the maxlength
   if(maxLength == currentValue.length){
       //move to next field
       $(this).next().focus();
   };
});
```

On button press gather all the values from the inputs and display

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //set the variable to append ti
    var dateDisplay = '';
    //iterate over the inputs
    $('#dateInput input').each(function(){
       //if dateDisplay exists (will explain soon)
       if(dateDisplay && $(this).val() != ''){
           //append the value
           dateDisplay += $(this).val() + '/';
       } else {
           //if the value is blank, make the variable false.
           dateDisplay = false;
       };
    });

    //now check the variable
    if(dateDisplay){
        //if it's all good, remove the last character (/) and display
        alert(dateDisplay.slice(0,-1));
    }
    return false;
});
```

This doesn't check for validity, just handles the general UX.

Comment: Thank you, but I need it in only one textbox instead of splitting it up into 3 different ones.

Comment: No native input has slashes in it.  This is how you make look like there are slashes.